# Using loop to accept additional user input until user enters a value that ends the input

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I need some help with using a loop to accept additional user input until the user enters a value that ends the input. My problem starts from the line with the statement "System.out.println("Are you are finished? Enter Y/N in uppercase") Below is my code.

public class EmployeeData {

```
//declare variables
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int id;
private double hourlyWage;

//constructors
public EmployeeData(String firstName, String lastName, int id, double hourlyWage){

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.id = id;
    this.hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
}

// getters and setters

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public double getHourlyWage() {
    return hourlyWage;
}

public void setHourlyWage(double hourlyWage) {
    this.hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
}

//method to return string
public String toString(){
    return "Employee Name: " + this.firstName +" "+ this.lastName + "\n"+ "Employee ID: " +this.id + "\n"+ "Hourly Wage "+ this.hourlyWage;
}
```

}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employee {

```
public static void main(String[] args){


    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int id;
    double hourlyWage;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your First Name");
    firstName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your Last Name");
    lastName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your ID Number");
    id = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your Hourly Wage");
    hourlyWage = input.nextDouble();


    EmployeeData em1 =  new EmployeeData("firstName" , "lastName" , id, hourlyWage);

    em1.setFirstName(firstName);
    em1.setLastName(lastName);
    em1.setId(id);
    em1.setHourlyWage(hourlyWage);



    String x = em1.toString();
    System.out.println(x);


    System.out.println("Are you are finished? Enter Y/N in uppercase");
    char c = input.next().charAt(0);
    if(c == 'N'){
        System.out.println("Enter your First Name");
        firstName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your Last Name");
        lastName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your ID Number");
        id = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your Hourly Wage");
        hourlyWage = input.nextDouble();


        EmployeeData em2 =  new EmployeeData("firstName" , "lastName" , id, hourlyWage);

        em2.setFirstName(firstName);
        em2.setLastName(lastName);
        em2.setId(id);
        em2.setHourlyWage(hourlyWage);



        String z = em2.toString();
        System.out.println(z);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("You have finished.");
    }



}
```

}

Comment: **Please** don't post images of code. Edit your post. Paste your code here. Highlight, press ctrl-k.

Comment: You would need a while loop, I do not see one in your code

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have pasted my entire code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a loop. Don't call `Scanner.next()` here (it won't consume trailing whitespace). And I would add a call to `String.toUpperCase()`. Finally, to answer your question, use a `while` loop. And you can perform the assignment before you test that the character isn't `N`. Like,

```
char c;
while ((c = input.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0)) != 'N') {
    System.out.println("Enter your First Name");
    firstName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your Last Name");
    lastName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your ID Number");
    id = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your Hourly Wage");
    hourlyWage = input.nextDouble();

    EmployeeData em2 = new EmployeeData("firstName", "lastName", id, hourlyWage);

    em2.setFirstName(firstName);
    em2.setLastName(lastName);
    em2.setId(id);
    em2.setHourlyWage(hourlyWage);

    // String z = em2.toString();
    System.out.println(em2);
}
System.out.println("You have finished.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while loop` and prompt for input after you have done what you need. The loop will be repeated **until** a certain condition is met. i.e. until the user inputs the condition in the prompt (which you can put at the end of your execution block)

```
while(input != "value for exit") 
{

// do your code

//prompt for input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very basics of programming, however as you stated you are new to Java - Advise you to read about `recursive functions` in general then implement it following recursive approach.